# Is it possible to resolve the caller instance in a Ninject factory method via IContext?

Tags: c#, .net, ninject

I guess this is a very simple scenario that I am trying to achieve.

I am just wondering whether or not it's possible to fetch the calling instance in a Ninject factory method.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var standardKernelCaller = new StandardKernelCaller();

        standardKernelCaller.Call();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface IA
{
}

public class A : IA
{
    public int Parameter { get; }

    public A(int parameter)
    {
        Parameter = parameter;
    }
}

public class Module : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IA>().ToMethod(Create);
    }

    private static A Create(IContext context)
    {
        var number = // resolve the caller (StandardKernelCaller) Magic Number using context...
        return new A(number);
    }
}

public class StandardKernelCaller
{
    public const int MagicNumber = 42;

    public void Call()
    {
        var standardKernel = new StandardKernel(new Module());

        var stuff = standardKernel.Get<IA>();
    }
}
```

I am not too sure if this is a good practice. At the moment in the related production code I am using something like:

```
public abstract class BusinessApiController<TBusinessLogic> : ApiController
    where TBusinessLogic : class, IBusinessLogic
{
    protected TBusinessLogic BusinessLogic { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(controllerContext);

        BusinessLogic = CreateBusinessLogic();
    }

    protected virtual TBusinessLogic CreateBusinessLogic()
    {
        var businessLogic = BusinessLogicFactory.Create<TBusinessLogic>(this.GetOwinContext());

        return businessLogic;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (BusinessLogic != null)
            {
                BusinessLogic.Dispose();
                BusinessLogic = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}


public abstract class BusinessController<TBusinessLogic> : Controller
    where TBusinessLogic : class, IBusinessLogic
{
    protected TBusinessLogic BusinessLogic { get; private set; }

    protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);

        BusinessLogic = CreateBusinessLogic();
    }

    protected virtual TBusinessLogic CreateBusinessLogic()
    {
        var businessLogic = BusinessLogicFactory.Create<TBusinessLogic>(this.GetOwinContext());

        return businessLogic;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (BusinessLogic != null)
            {
                BusinessLogic.Dispose();
                BusinessLogic = null;
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

But I am not a huge fan of the hardcoded "owinContext" parameter name in the factory below:

```
public static class BusinessLogicFactory
{
    // Potentially obsolete readonly / configuration kernel in upcoming Ninject versions
    private static readonly StandardKernel StandardKernel = new StandardKernel(new BusinessLogicsNinjectModule());

    public static TBusinessLogic Create<TBusinessLogic>(IOwinContext owinContext)
    {
        // Potential refactoring: get the argument name via expression binding or use Ninject providers
        var businessLogic = StandardKernel.Get<TBusinessLogic>(new ConstructorArgument("owinContext", owinContext));

        return businessLogic;
    }
}
```

And here is an example of a simplified version of the Ninject module:

```
public class BusinessLogicsNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IUserManagementBusinessLogic>().To<UserManagementBusinessLogic>();
        Bind<IAppointmentManagementBusinessLogic>().To<AppointmentManagementBusinessLogic>();
        Bind<ITeamAppointmentManagementBusinessLogic>().To<TeamAppointmentManagementBusinessLogic>();
    }
}
```

By the way if there is a better way of doing for BusinessLogic injection or better design overall, I would love to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For know, let me answer your first question:
In your example, it's not possible to determine the instance or the type of `StandardKernelCaller` from `IContext`.

If you would *inject* (ctor-injection, property injection) the value into `StandardKernelCaller` instead of *resolve* (`Get`) it, then you would be gather the type `StandardKernelCaller` from `IContext`.
If property-injection would be applied, maybe you could even get the instance of `StandardKernelCaller` (I suspect it's not available though).

However, you can pass arguments to the `Get` call: a name (string) for named bindings (resolves to binding registered with the same name, throws if no matching binding available) and `IParameter`'s. `IParameter`s are made available on `IContext`.

Answer (score 1):

First, use Ninject.Web.Common+Ninject.Web.WebApi extension, so that your controllers don't depend on service locator: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki

Second, your business logic being dependent on `owinContext` seems to be a design smell. Separation of concerns should be followed, here it seems you are mixing infrastructure/business layer.

Third, if you really want it, you can pass `owinContext` trough a method call as a parameter.

Fourth, if you really want it to pass trough a constructor, you can use Ninject.Extensions.Factory:
https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory/wiki

```
public interface IBusinessLogicFactory<TBusinessLogic>
{
    TBusinessLogic Create(IOwinContext owinContext);
}

var factory = kernel.Bind<IBusinessLogicFactory<TBusinessLogic>>().ToFactory(() => new TypeMatchingArgumentInheritanceInstanceProvider());
...
var businessLogic = kernel.Get<IBusinessLogicFactory<TBusinessLogic>>().Create(owinContext);
```

Comment: actually the IOwinContext (which is wrapped in a proxy) is for providing some access to the Identity users and who is the current user (the latter is something I could really get elsewhere). However I admit that this could be refactored though to pass the current user as a method parameter when it's relevant.